# Does every vertex has at least one outgoing edge implies the graph contains a cycle?

Tags: graph-theory

I can proof it for finite vertex because $v_i\rightarrow v_{i+1}$ (outgoing edge) condition. But what about the infinite case? Is there any counter example for infinite case?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: An edge from $v_i$ to $v_{i+1}$ of an directed graph @bof

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in title @bof.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have vertices $v_k$ for each integer $k$. And $v_k \rightarrow v_{k+1}$, and there are no other edges. Then every vertex has an outgoing edge, but there's no cycle.